# Run openMP on Eclipse

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to run a simple example of openMP program on Ecplise since I have to implement a hybrid program with MPI and openMP. I have no problem with running MPI programs, but I can't get openMP programs to run. I added in project-> properties-> C / c ++ build-> settings-> miscellaneous-> other options and added -fopenmp. But I still have problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when i build the project i get this error:

```
Invoking: GCC C Linker
mpicc -L/home/rob/openmpi/lib -Xlinker -fopenmp -o "Test" ./src/Test.o    -lmpi
/usr/bin/ld: -f may not be used without -shared
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:43: Test] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

How can I fix this error? The openMPI library was installed on ubuntu.

Comment: Some `mpicc` scripts are picky about the order in which you specify things. Trying moving all `-L` and -`l` options to the end. Also: what is `-Xlinker`? Do you need that? If so, see if that one expects options because it is the word immediately after it that the error is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"-Xlinker" passes the next argument to the linker (ld) which in turn parses it as its own "-f" option.  Try removing "-Xlinker" or add a linker flag after it if needed.    https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html